# Velocity: Either jQuery or Velocity's jQuery shim must first be loaded with webpack

Tags: webpack, velocity

I'm implementing webpack with a project uses velocity.js,
when eve i run the project it returned an error 
`Velocity: Either jQuery or Velocity's jQuery shim must first be loaded`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make jQuery available in all modules use the `ProvidePlugin`:

```
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery",
            "window.jQuery": "jquery"
        })
    ]
};
```

See [webpack doc shiming modules](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/shimming-modules) for more information.

Comment: thanks that solve it , also I was loading jquery using loaders 
` { test:/\.(jsx|js)$/, exclude: /node_modules/,  loader: 'imports?jQuery=jquery,$=jquery,this=>window },`
what is the diffrence ?

Comment: The `imports-loader` makes jquery available as local variables within a closure, but via the global variable (tied to the `window` object in a browser). In my approach the `jQuery` object is also tied to the `window` object which is how jQuery works by default and if no module loading system is in place. Velocity might rely on the binding on the window object, I don't know the details here. Please consider marking the answer as correct if it worked for you.